# Killing parent process from a child process with Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, multiprocessing, fork

In my (very simplified) scenario, in python 2.7, I have 2 processes:

1. Parent process, which doing some tasks.
2. Child process, which needs to kill the parent process after X time.

Creation of child process:

```
killer = multiprocessing.Process(...)
killer.start()
```

The child process executes the following code after X time (simplified version of the code):

```
process = psutil.Process(parent_pid)
...
if time_elapsed:
    while True:
        process.kill()
        if not process.is_alive:
            exit()
```

The problem is that it's leaving the parent as a zombie process, and the child is never exiting because the parent is still alive.

The same code works as expected in Windows.

All the solutions that I saw were talking about the parent process waiting for the child to finish by calling `killer.join()`, but in my case, the parent is the one who does the task, and it shouldn't wait for its child.

What is the best way to deal with a scenario like that?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have to kill the process instead of exiting from it using something like `threading.event`? And is there any good reason why you can't just change the tasks of parent and child process?

Comment: Does `killer.daemon = True` before starting the process help?

Comment: @JohnAnderson it didn't change anything

Comment: @Felix I'm not always using the timeout feature, it's only one of the many options in my program. In a later design I might use something like `threading.event`, but for now just killing it is fine for me.

Comment: If killing the parent makes the parent a zombie, then the problem is with the grandparent.  If the parent is in fact a zombie, the grandparent should wait on it to clear it out of the process table.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `os.getppid()` to retrieve the parent's PID, and kill it with `os.kill()`.

E.g. `os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGKILL)`

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html and https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#module-signal for reference.

A mwo:

Parent:

```
import subprocess32 as subprocess

subprocess.run(['python', 'ch.py'])
```

Child:

```
import os
import signal

os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```