# How can I kill my docker container from the running python script?

Tags: python, docker

I am running a docker where there's a python script running. At some moment, in my python script I will want to kill the parent docker running this python script. How can I kill it from this python script?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.13

# Variable arguments
ENV AM_I_IN_A_DOCKER_CONTAINER True
WORKDIR /code

#Install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

#Copy code into the container
COPY ./example/ /code/example/


#Start the app
CMD ["python", "example/example.py"]
```

Docker is running from an AWS task.

Example.py:

```
import threading
import time 

def start_worker():
    #do some stuff
    time.sleep(10)
    print("WE ARE EXITING")
    print("EXIT")
    exit()
        
ce = threading.Thread(target=start_worker)
ce.start()
```

Comment: If the script is the only process in the container just stop the script itself

Comment: I'm doing an exit() but the docker it's not being killed

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Is the Python application the only thing running in the container, or is something else launching it?

Comment: I would gess that the the issue here is the fact that you are using threads? You are exiting the thread but the main thread might still be running?
Could you try to do this without threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you basically need to send SIGTERM or SIGKILL to the thread's process. Which is possible by the following code:

```
import os
import signal

os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

In order to stop the container regardles if the thread's process is the first container's process (in your example executed by: `CMD ["python", "example/example.py"]`), you just need to kill process with PID 1. Which is possible by the following code:

```
import signal
pid = 1
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Inspired by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51306383/5372462)